# Array of input field data cant make the required option in REACT

Tags: reactjs

```
export const InputData = [
    {
        id: "email",
        name: "email",
        type: "email",
        classname: "w-full p-3 text-sm border-2 border-gray-300 focus:border-primary-600 placeholder-gray-500 rounded-md focus:outline-none",
        placeholder: "Email",
        required: "required"
    }
]

...

{InputData.map((item) => {
    return <input
        id={item.id}
        name={item.name}
        type={item.type}
        className={item.classname}
        placeholder={item.placeholder}
        required ={item.required}
    />
}
)}
```

I'm trying to make a array of input fields but I dont know how to make the required field on the array but gives me a error, someone can help me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use this:

```js
export const InputData = [{
  id: "email",
  name: "email",
  type: "email",
  classname: "w-full p-3 text-sm border-2 border-gray-300 focus:border-primary-600 placeholder-gray-500 rounded-md focus:outline-none",
  placeholder: "Email",
  required: true
}]
```